# DTSS software list?

Tags: basic

I'm continuing my effort to track down the original author of the early game Chase. I have pretty much concluded it was written on the [GE-635](http://GE-600%20series) running [Dartmouth Time Sharing System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dartmouth_Time_Sharing_System) (DTSS) and [Dartmouth BASIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dartmouth_BASIC).

So is anyone aware of a list of DTSS software? I've poked about on archive.org, but nothing is coming up.

Comment: A little more info might help. For instance, I have no idea what DTSS is, and I don't know what Chase is.

Comment: And you call yourself a retrocomputerist! (waggles finger) Fixed.

Comment: See also the OP's earlier question: [Early game, “Chase” or “Escape!” and many others](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/6662/731).